# How to import a test script with multiple steps in rally?

Tags: rally

We have a spread sheet with multiple test steps created and want to import it into rally. How can we do this?

Comment: What have you tried?  What have you searched for pertaining to this topic? Please also read over this to formulate a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We aren't free contractors here.

Comment: I got the answer i was after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rally Add-In for Excel would be your best option.  Once gotcha to importing Test Case Steps with the add-in is you will need to make sure you specify a Step Index for each step.

You can find more information about the add-in here:
https://help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel-installation-user-guide